# Corrections need to be made but im not understanding how to do said directions

Tags: html, css

So these were the questions I missed.

- has a 'form' element that is 600px when the window is wider than 600px
- has exactly one input with a name of 'pet_name' and an associated label with the content 'Name'
- has exactly one 'select' element with a name of 'pet_type' and an associated label with the content 'Type'

And this is what i tried
HTML

```
<div>
  <label for="Name">pet_name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="pet_name">

</div>

<div>
  <label for="Type">pet_type</label>
  <select id="type" name="pet_type">
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="Zebra">Zebra</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="bio">Biography</label>
  <textarea id="bio" name="pet_bio"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="email">Owner's Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="owner-email" name="pet_owner_email">
</div>

<div>
  <button type="submit">Create new pet</button>
  <id="new-pet-submit-button"</id>
</div>

<div>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

CSS

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

```
  form {
    width: auto;
  }

  label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
  }

  input,
  select,
  textarea {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

I understand the second part( I think) I need to remove name="pet_name"
The other two im a little hesitant on. Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-width: 600px` for the form media query.
Other suggestions is about case sensitivity of `for` attribute

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  form {
    width: 600px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  form {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
  }
  label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
  }
  input,
  select,
  textarea {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="name">pet_name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="pet_name">

</div>

<div>
  <label for="type">pet_type</label>
  <select id="type" name="pet_type">
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="Zebra">Zebra</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="bio">Biography</label>
  <textarea id="bio" name="pet_bio"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="email">Owner's Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="owner-email" name="pet_owner_email">
</div>

<div>
  <button type="submit">Create new pet</button>
  <id="new-pet-submit-button" </id>
</div>

<div>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```